# Importing a file to python and executing it multiple times

Tags: python, loops, import, raspberry-pi4

Hello and apologies if my below comments seem basic, I am fairly new to Python and I think I am importing files incorrectly.

I am running a translation stage from a Rpi 4B, I have set up a code that is able to move the stage how I like, however when I am trying to integrate this into a larger program, that's designed to automatically search for a designated spot, I am having issues getting the imported movement files to run more than once.

I have the search code set up so that the stage will move a set distance, stop, an LDR circuit will detect if the desired spot has been reached, if it has then do X, Y Z, if it has not move again. It is the move again bit thats giving me issues. I can import a movement once, but the second loop in the system will not work.

I have figured out that it is not my larger code at fault (with a simple print ("this bits working")) in the loop where the import movement is meant to go, as well as other testing in small files to determine this issue.

Please see below the simplified versions of the file that calls the function, and the sub function.

Master file:

```
import Right

for i in range(10):
    Right
```

Sub file:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

X_Pul = 11
Y_Pul = 15
Dir = 13

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(Dir, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(X_Pul, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Y_Pul, GPIO.OUT)

print ("going right")

def Right ():

    GPIO.output(Dir, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(X_Pul, GPIO.HIGH)

    time.sleep(0.001)

    GPIO.output(X_Pul, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(Dir, GPIO.LOW)

for i in range(100):
    Right()
    time.sleep(0.005)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

As said above, the sub file works on its own, but I am unable to get it running multiple times in the master file. I am relatively new to Python and learning as I go, so any and all input will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: If `Right` is a module, `Right` as in your loop won't do anything, it would be just like `42` or whatever...

Comment: Since Right is the name of the module imported into the master you need Right.Right() to run the function Right in the Right module.  So loop becomes: `for i in range(10):
    Right.Right()`

Answer (score 0):

You can save your sub file as sub.py. Then in your master file you can do

```
import sub
for i in range(10):
    sub.Right()
```

Make sure they are in the same directory